# Is there a JavaScript idiom to change "undefined" to "null"?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, idioms, coercion

There's quite a few JavaScript idioms that coerce between types and similar things.

`!` can convert anything falsey to boolean `true`, `!!` can convert anything falsey to actual boolean `false`, `+` can convert `true`, `false`, or a string representing a number into an actual number, etc.

Is there something similar that converts `undefined` to `null`?

Now I'm using ternary `? :` but it would be cool to know if I'm missing a useful trick.

---

OK, let me **contrive** an example ...

```
function callback(value) {
  return value ? format(value) : null;
}
```

`callback` is called by 3rd party code which sometimes passes `undefined`.
The 3rd party code can handle `null` being passed back, but not `undefined`. `format()` is also 3rd party and can't handle being passed either `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a nice quick way to convert between them, but if it helps: `undefined == null` returns true, unlike `undefined === null`

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @VamshiGudipati: I was going to, but people would just tell me some other way to do that, so I decided not to. I just want to improve my vocabulary of JavaScript idioms and I think that's enough to make a good question. The whole point of idioms is that they have many uses.

Comment: Instead of converting them, you can use the truly or falsy value expression, `!!undefined // false` and `!!null // false`

Comment: @VamshiGudipati: I made up a contrived example anyway, just in case it helps. If it hinders I might remove it again (-:

Comment: "There's quite a few JavaScript idioms that coerce between types and similar things." --- those are not idioms. To convert something to a boolean idiomatically you use `Boolean()` function.

Comment: I don't see how an operation to cast from `undefined` to `null` would be useful in your example. Are you trying to implement your `callback` as `return toNullIfUndefined(value) && format(value)`? I'd argue that your current code is clear, clean, and idiomatic.

Comment: Or was the example wrong and you meant to have it `return format(value == undefined ? null : value)`?

Comment: @Bergi: It could well be that for the contrived example that's as idiomatic as it gets. That's why I initially resisted making up an example (-: I should've included that `format()` can't handle being passed either `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @hippietrail Well using `&&` instead of a ternary is rather unidiomatic, so this wouldn't have benefited from a `toNullIfUndefined` operator anyway.

Comment: In case you're wondering why this is useful on some occasions - Angular form control object can be 'set' with an object, but if a property exists and is undefined you get an error 'Property X missing'. If that property had been 'null' you wouldn't have got the error.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Javascript now supports a null-coalescing operator: `??`. It may not be production-ready (consult the [support table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#Browser_compatibility)), but it's certainly safe to use with Node or a transpiler (TypeScript, Babel, etc.).

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator),

> The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

Much as `||` can provide a "default" value when the left operand is falsey, `??` provides a "default" value if the left operand is null or undefined. You can use this to coerce undefined to null:

```
    // OR operator can coerce 'defined' values
    "value"   || null;    // "value"
    0         || null;    // null
    false     || null;    // null
    ""        || null;    // null
    undefined || null;    // null
    
    // The null-coalescing operator will only coerce undefined or null
    "value"   ?? null;    // "value"
    0         ?? null;    // 0
    false     ?? null;    // false
    ""        ?? null;    // ""
    undefined ?? null;    // null
```

An example based on the question:

```
    function mustNotReturnUndefined(mightBeUndefined) { // can return null
        // Substitute empty string for null or undefined
        let result = processValue(mightBeUndefined ?? "");

        // Substitute null for undefined
        return result ?? null;
    }
```

Answer (score 24):

`undefined || null`  - or any falsey || null - will return null

Comment: What about the case where false and 0 are valid value that should not be converted?

Comment: what about it??

Comment: What I mean is that it looks like your answer will fail when compared to these 2.  Do you have an option which does a strict type check and only covers the undefined?  I was looking for something that didn't use a for loop because I am looking to use it in a lot of methods to normalize the inputs

Comment: In that case you can use a ternary expression, similar to the example presented in the question: `value === undefined ? null : value`

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly old question and probably my answer is a little late, but I decided for myself in the following way:

```js
const valueOrNull = (value = null) => value;

const a = { d: '' };
valueOrNull(a.b?.c) === null; // true
valueOrNull(a.d) === '';      // true
valueOrNull() === null;       // true
```

Any `undefined` value will get `null` as the default value;

Answer (score -2):

```
public static replaceUndefinedWithNull(object: any) {
 if (isUndefined(object)) {
  return null;
 }
return object;
}
```